# How to join nested values into one column with tidyjson?

Tags: json, r, dataframe, tidyr

I want to join two values in one column instead of spreading

```
'{"name": {"first": "bob", "last": "jones"}, "age": 32}' %>%
spread_values(
first.name = jstring("name", "first"), 
age = jnumber("age")
) %>%
unite(conc, c("first.name", "age"), sep=" ")
```

But I keep having the following error

> All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
>   The following do not:
>   c("first.name", "age")

My desire output is to have one new column "conc" replacing both first.name and age and that concatenate every string value. such as "jones 32"

Which is weird because if I remove the last line it gives me a proper data.frame and I can access first.name and age.

Any hint?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: `'{"name": {"first": "bob", "last": "jones"}, "age": 32}' %>% jsonlite::fromJSON() %>% as.data.frame()` is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Though `tbl_json` objects inherit from `tbl_df`, they sometimes do not play nicely once you are done parsing and begin to do further manipulation in `tidyjson` and `dplyr`.  The reason is that you have additional methods and attributes tagging along that are not really necessary anymore.

As a result, once finished parsing, it is a good habit to use `tbl_df` or `as_data_frame` to strip off the `tbl_json` component of the object.  I prefer `tbl_df` because it is shorter.

I am using the development version from github: `devtools::install_github('jeremystan/tidyjson')`

I could not reproduce the error that you mention, but this seems to work:

```
library(tidyjson)
library(tidyr)

"{\"name\": {\"first\": \"bob\", \"last\": \"jones\"}, \"age\": 32}" %>% 
spread_values(first.name = jstring("name","first")
  , age = jnumber("age")
) %>% 
tbl_df() %>% 
unite(conc, c("first.name", "age"), sep = " ")

#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   document.id   conc
#> *       <int>  <chr>
#> 1           1 bob 32
```

Other food for thought when concatenating strings is to use `paste()` or `paste0()` within `mutate`.  `mutate` is supported by `tidyjson`, as well, so it can be used in the pipeline while parsing JSON.  `paste(.,collapse=',')` can be really helpful when aggregating multiple rows with `summarize`, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(jsonlite)
json <- lapply( paste0("[",'{"name": {"first": "bob", "last": "jones"}, "age": 32}',"]"), 
                function(x) jsonlite::fromJSON(x))
##json is a list

df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(json), nrow=1, ncol=3, byrow=T))

df <- df %>% unite(Name, X1, X3, sep = " ")
df <- subset(df, select=-X2)
colnames(df) <- c("conc")
df
```